# How to create a relative path pointing to the "xxxxxxxx.default" profile in the Firefox Profiles folder?

Tags: firefox, path, firefox-profile

I created a bat file pointing to my Firefox default profile

```
%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\4aucnox9.default
```

but I really would like to make it usable also for every `xxxxxxxx.default` profile in different computers.

Is this possible ?

Comment: You can easily do this with PowerShell.

Comment: Please do not add "solved" to the title. Accept the answer instead. (You may have to wait until you're allowed to accept your own answer, but still).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution positioning the `.bat` file one directory down (inside the profile folder) so the relative path to any `xxxxxxxx.default` profile will be one directory up simply using the following 3 signs

```
../
```

in place of `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\4aucnox9.default`.